# Can I say something like this?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases, phrase-choice

I get a little confused when I'm trying to say something like this:

> 1. This is a sample of my always changing taste in movies.
> 2. This is a sample of my always in change taste in movies.
> 3. This is a sample of my always in changing taste in movies.

Are those 3 sentences correct? Why (If Yes or Not)?

Comment: Do you mean "sample" as in you have a list of different movies that you've liked over time, or do you mean "example", as in you've just changed you taste in movies again?

Comment: I think the first one, the list meaning, but sample here is sort of indifferent in my opinion, isn't it?

Just trying to express something (my taste in movies) in constantly change.

Comment: Are you going to share a list of movies after that statement? If not, sample won't work. If yes, then #1 is perfectly fine. If you aren't going to change the list and you want to say, these are movies you like, then you would probably want to word it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said #1 is the most correct, although it's not very natural.  However in contrast to what others have said "sample" is fine if you plan to offer a short list of some of your favorite movies.

A more natural way to say this is to use "ever-changing" instead of "always changing":

> Here is a sample of my ever-changing taste in movies: [Movie A, Movie B, Movie C, etc.].

Answer (score 0):

(1) is the only sentence with reasonably correct form. However the context is unclear.

Sample usually means selecting some subset from a large set. Typically this would mean more than one. So you're holding two romantic comedy movies and a horror flick.

Example is a better word probably and would indicate that you have chosen a movie that the listener wouldn't have expected you to select. So the listener thinks you like romantic comedy movies and you show a horror flick.